# Android Application starts at beginning after the application is minimized and refocused.

Tags: java, android, android-intent

The application brings up the startup `intent`. The startup `intent` does some checks for updates. After the process is completed a new `intent` is loaded and the old one is `finish()`.

When a user `minimizes` the application and then brings the application back to `focus` the first `intent` is loaded and the process checking for updates starts again.

How do I bring the `intent` the user had last back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to activity in AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

So it should look like this:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance" />
```